# Return 'default' in an int method to pass to switch

Tags: java

So I am making a test class for an assignment for school, and it looks like this:

```
public class Tester{
  //variables....  some for the object to be tested, others for a Base object to be tested against

  public void test(SpecialObject objectToBeTested){
    SpecialObject baseObject = new SpecialObject();
    int testCase = this.compareObjects(objectToBeTested, baseObject); //compare the two
    switch (testCase){
      case 1: System.out.println("CASE 1"); break;
      case 2: System.out.println("CASE 2"); break;
      default: System.out.println("Default, everything is good"); break;
      //can't just make this case 0, because I think the switch requires a default
      //so how do I pass an int to trigger the default?
    }
  }
  public int compareObject(SpecialObject one, SpecialObject two) {
    //compare one.this1 and two.that1
    if ( one.this1 = two.that1 ) {return 1;};
    //compare one.this2 and two.that2
    if ( one.this2 = two.that2 ) {return 2;};
    //......
    // HERE IS WHERE I AM CONFUSED
    // I want to do something like
    return default;
    //or
    return "default";
    // but can't because I need to pass an int
  }
}
```

Since I am trying to keep all the comparisons in one method (although this will later be abstracted into multiple methods) I am trying to pass an integer back to `test()` with an integer for the switch method.   Trying to keep with good information, I want to tell myself what particular comparison is failing, I think I need to pass something to the switch method to use default.   What should I return from the `compareObject(one, two)` to trigger the default case in the switch method IF everything checks out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'default' in a switch statement is called if the variable doesn't match any of the cases.  If you have case 1 and case 2, any int that is NOT 1 or 2 will go to the default block.

Answer (score 0):

You can return anything `int` other than a 1 or a 2. You choose what you want 'default' to be. Maybe a 0 or a -1 or something else.

Also see Thomas's answer about the `switch`. Make sure you understand what a `switch' statement does.